# JMeter Load Test for Separate ID based URL'S

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

1. Something data-driven, i.e. JMeter variable originating from CSV data set config like `${userid}`
2. Something random i.e. between 1 and 100 using `__Random()` function like `${__Random(1,100)}`

These are the two methods I got. It is compulsory to generate CSV data set configuration in Jmeter. Or else the second method is enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in position to use random - go for it, it will save time and make your test more independent as you won't have to worry about creating CSV file, performing CSV Data Set configuration, copying the csv files to JMeter slaves in case of [remote testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html), etc.

However it may be a good idea to save random values into JMeter variables like

```
${__Random(1,100, userid)}
```

and saving this `userid` into .jtl results file via [Sample Variables property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) by adding the next line to [user.properties file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

```
sample_variables=userid
```

This way you will be able to see which random user id has caused error or re-use this column to replay the test.